# For which simple closed curves $\gamma$, $\int\limits_{\gamma} z^{2}+z+1\, dz=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

For which simple closed curves $\gamma$ is $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma} z^{2}+z+1\, dz=0$

Could someone help me through this problem?

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: $z^2+z+1$ has an antiderivative in the entire complex plane....

Comment: If and consider also the theorem of Jordan curve

Comment: What do you mean by "If and consider"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every polynomial has a primitive and so you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to conclude that the integral of a polynomial around a closed curve is zero.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(z)$ is holomorphic, then for any closed curve $\gamma$, we have
$$\int_\gamma f(z)= 0$$    As other also commented: See [cauchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)

Comment: Also: any polynomial $f(z)$ is analytic -- or should we say [holomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function#Examples)!

Answer (score 0):

Yet anouther way to see this is to note that the polynomial is entire. Since it is entire, we have that, by the deformation invariance theorem, the integral is zero (since the loop can be deformed continuously to a point in the domain of analyticicity).